# Retrieve the filesize using SMBLIBRARY

Tags: c#, allocation, smb

When retrieving the size of a file, we currently use the AllocationSize attribute.

However, the AllocationSize retrieves the size of the file **on disk** which is not necessarily the size of the content of the file.
How do i retrieve size of the content of the file?

The code to retrieve the allocationSize:

```
if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    List<QueryDirectoryFileInformation> fileList;
    status = fileStore.QueryDirectory(out fileList, directoryHandle, "*", FileInformationClass.FileDirectoryInformation);
    status = fileStore.CloseFile(directoryHandle);

    //
    // Here we are casting each item in the fileList to a FileDirectoryInformation 
    // type that holds the  AllocationSize attribute
    // 
    foreach(FileDirectoryInformation file in fileList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Filename: {file.FileName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"File Size: {file.**AllocationSize **/ 1024}KB");
        Console.WriteLine($"Created Date: {file.CreationTime.ToString("f")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Last Modified Date: {file.LastWriteTime.ToString("f")}");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();                            
    }
}
```

Comment: The size you are getting is the number of bytes which is not what is shown in file explorer.  The number shown in file explorer is rounded and may be off by a small amount.

Comment: What is shown in the properties of the file in file explorer is the Size and the Size on disk. The allocation size returned by smllibrary is the Size on disk (exactly). However, i want to know the Size (of the content).

Comment: Why would they be different?

Comment: Because of the segmentation of the disc (tracks, sectors etc). The file size on disc is often greater than the actual size because the last track/sector is not filled completely. The file size on disk as shown in the file explorer is exactly the size returned in the AllocationSize. The size as shown in the file explorer is exactly the size in bytes when i read the file. However, i don't want to have to read every file just to know its file size.

Comment: You need special tools to get the overhead of a file and in most cases the overhead is not important.  The file size on disk is always greater than the actual size (not often, but always).  You can easily estimate the overhead if necessary.  The overhead only becomes important when a disk get badly fragmented and is the main reason you should regularly defragment.

Comment: You're missing the point. I want to know the actual size of the file so i can allocate the correct amount of memory before populating a memory buffer with the content of the file. I asked TalAloni (creator of smblibrary) and he pointed out that the 'EndOfFile' property contains the actual size of the file.

Comment: You cannot allocate the overhead associated with the file and it is not continuous.  It is part of the OS and not part of c# code.